# $PATH of directory shows in bash but not in editor

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set a path in my `$PATH`:

```
/home/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/bin
```

When I `echo $PATH` it is there, but when I open `vscode`, and check the `process.env.PATH` it isn't there. I am not sure why it is there in the bash, but not in the editor. This is causing issues when running tasks in the editor.

I do see that this is in both the bash and the editor:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

So, what would be the best way to find where that is set? I am thinking that if I set the first path in the same location that it should be in both the editor and bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the issue is that when you are modifying your PATH you are not using "export" when setting the variable

using "export" is required to make a variable (which PATH is) available to sub-processes - so

```
export PATH=$PATH:/new/path
```

should work.

**Update:**

Apparently the solution in this case was to use a .gnomerc file

Comment: I have that in my `.bashrc`. I copied it to my `.profile`, and it still only displays in the bash, and not the editor. `export PATH="/home/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: How are you loading your editor ?  It seems like its not being launched from your bash shell ?

Comment: no, I am launching it from the desktop (gnome 3) it is saved in my favorites, and `dash to dock` is where I click

Comment: If I launch the editor from the bash `code ./path/to/dir` it loads the proper `$PATH`

Comment: ??? I'm guessing if you launch it from bash it works ???  Your problem is that the path is not being altered in the parent (ie gnome 3).

Comment: I've never tried it, but try creating an  executable .gnomerc file which exports your path, then log out and log in again.

Comment: Creating a `.gnomerc` worked!

Comment: You should update the answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn - Ta.